# Replace div with JQuery from another controller-view

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

Imagine I have the following 'partial' which is generated through a bunch of views:

```
<div id="funstuff">
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
</div>
```

Through the usage of codeigniter, I can reuse views (which I do a lot), and I would like to dynamically replace the 'funstuff' div with the contents from another view. Its controller method is still in the same class:

```
class FunnyThings extends CI_Controller {

   public function index() {
   $this->load->view('funpage_view');
   }

   public function funview() {
   $this->load->view('fun_partial_view');
   }
}
```

Basically, with Jquery I can replace that view with different content:

```
$('#funstuff').replaceWith('<div><h2>New heading</h2></div>');
```

However, how can I get the content from the other view, dynamically and replace it with the div I've selected?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery has a convenience method called `load()` for this, see http://api.jquery.com/load/ for more informations.

In your case, the line would go something like this:

```
$('#funstuff').load('FunnyThings/funview');
```

Where `FunnyThings/funview` is the relative URL to your controller.

Comment: Superb, exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know the other view's `id` or a `class` you can do like this:

```
// if you know the class name (other-view)
    $('#funstuff').replaceWith($(".other-view")); 

// if you know the id (other-view)    
    $('#funstuff').replaceWith($("#other-view"));
```

Comment: This would be local, as the other answer pointed out, the .load() method does the Ajaxified form as I need it :) Thanks though!

Comment: Sorry I didn't read your question fully. Obviously if you want to load an external resource, you must use `.load()` method.